# Can't make react-native-maps with borderRadius

Tags: css, react-native, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with react native and i want to add borderRadius into my google map view but didn't work

```
<View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          flex: 1,
          borderRadius: 30,
          margin: 20,
        }}
      >
        <Map />
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          marginTop: 40,        
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "center",
          height: 300,
          width: 370,
        }}
      >
```

Map Component :

```
const Map = () => {
  return (
    <MapView
      style={tw`flex-1`}
      customMapStyle={mapStyle}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

[result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfFy6.jpg)

So how can i do that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map the component in a view have a borderRadius and overflow propert set to "hidden" like this :

```js
const Map = () => {
  return (

    <View
      style={
        borderRadius: 50,
        overflow: "hidden"
      }
    >
      <MapView
        style={tw`flex-1`}
        customMapStyle={mapStyle}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
      />
    </View>
    
  );
};
```

Comment: hi, why did you remove the accepted tag from my answer ? and for the shadow you want you can add `opacity: 0.8` in the MapView Style and `backgroundColor: "black"` in the parent view

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, adding overflow and centering with alightItems

```
            <View style={{ 
                height: moderateScale(300) - 60, 
                zIndex: -1, 
                borderRadius: 10, 
                borderWidth: 1, 
                borderColor: userInterface.buttonSelectedFill, 
                overflow: 'hidden',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'}}>

                <MapView 
                    style={{flex: 1, height: '100%', width: '100%', borderRadius: 10, }} 
                    //ref={ map => {currentMap = map }}
                    //region={props.region}
                    rotateEnabled={false}
                    loadingEnabled={true}
                ></MapView>                
            </View>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer solved by adding overflow  `overflow: "hidden"`

Comment: No problem! Do you mind accepting it as the answer so this question can get flagged as completed? Thanks!

Comment: yea sure, dude another question can I make a shadow too? because I tried to make a shadow but didn't work, u have a solution for that?